# should structure definition (not instantiation) be placed in header file?

Tags: c, struct, typedef, header-files

I have one .c file and one .h.

I am not planning to have more than one .c file.

Should I put structure definition in the header file?

what is the best practice?

```
.h
typedef struct cow_s {
    int legs;
    char eyes;
} cow_t;
```

and

```
.c
cow_t *ptr_to_cow;
```

note: I do not want struct to become global.

Comment: Are you sure that you will not have more than one `.c` file in the future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have no intention to expose this structure to some other module (and you say you have only one module) there is no real reason to put it in a header file, except of keeping things ordered.

Comment: thanks much. I do want to keep things ordered, so will go with putting it in .h. I have another question/doubt that I want to clarify: If I instantiate that struct in .h, that becomes global, right? and if I do it in .c (as I am doing) it wont be global. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: @hari: If you instantiate it in .h then a copy of it gets created in every translation unit(h file + c file code) in which the file gets included, If you instantiate it in the .c file outside of any function then it becomes global to that particular file, other files can still access it by using the `extern` keyword.

Comment: @Als: Thanks. I do not want to make it global so I will instantiate inside a function and pass it around by pointer to it.

Answer (score 2):

Structure definition belongs in .h files (typically). If you want to hide the structure then put it in the .c file that will be using it.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you intend for your users to use the structure. If they are allowed to instantiate and modify the members then you need to place the definition in the header file. On the other hand, if the users do not need to have access to the structure members you should place it in the .c file.

Let's assume it's the latter case. If so, `cow_t` is opaque to the users and you'll need to create accessor functions for it. For instance:

```
cow_t *CreateCow( void )
{
  return malloc( cow_t );
}

void SacrificeCow( cow_t *cow )
{
  free( cow );
}

int GetNumberOfCowLegs( cow_t *cow )
{
  return cow->legs;
}

void SetNumberOfCowLegs( cow_t *cow, int numLegs )
{
  cow->legs = numLegs;
}
```

Comment: How I am thinking is: It gets instantiated in main() and passed to other functions via reference. This way other functions can make changes to it. That is okay, right?

Comment: @hari: You mean passed to other function via pointer; C does not have pass by reference. Are these other functions in the same .c file? If not, you'll have to place the struct in a header and have all the .c files that need to use it include that header.

Comment: My bad; yes, passing pointer to the struct. There is only 1 .c file be for clarity I am putting struct in the header.

Comment: @hari: If there is only 1 .c file you don't need a header, just place everything that you were going to put in the header at the top of this .c file.

Comment: I thought its always cleaner approach to have a header? no? Also, after I die, some other developer decides to add another .c, having a header would help :D

Comment: @hari: In general it is cleaner to split code into header and source files. But for small programs, that I fairly confident won't grow in scope, I just put everything into the source file. It's a matter of personal preference really.